# selecting a string from a record in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file containing records. The record format is as follows:

```
Record: XXXXXX [
{variable number of lines and content}
]
```

At some point within the record, there may be a string that begins with

`Start to do this thing`

I would like to extract the Record number and the line within the record that matches the word `Start'

Presently I am using

```
egrep "Record|Start" inputfile.txt >> outputfile.txt
```

but I must then remove manually the matched `Record` lines which to not have `Start` matched. Ideally I would like this to be done in a single step. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example file, repeated three times in a row with modifications:

```
Record: XXXXXX [
{variable number of lines and content}
Start to do this thing
]
Record: YYYYYY [
{variable number of lines and content}
Stop doing this thing
]
Record: ZZZZZZ [
{variable number of lines and content}
Start again
]
```

Then:

```
$ awk '/^Record:/ { r = $2 } /^Start/ { print r ":", $0 }' file
XXXXXX: Start to do this thing
ZZZZZZ: Start again
```

We simply pick up the record number/label as soon as we see a line starting with `Record:` and save it in the variable `r`.  Then, as we find a line starting with `Start` we print whatever record label we've found and the line.

If the line doesn't *start* with `Start`, you may have to change the regular expression from `/^Start/` to `/^ *Start/` which will allow any number of spaces between the word and the start of the line.

This will fail if there are *other* things in the file between the records that matches `Start`.

Comment: Thank you. While both answers provided so far have worked, I am choosing this as the correct one since it is easier for me to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

**Awk** solution:

Sample `input.txt` file:

```
Record: 111111 [
text
test
Start to do this thing
text
]
Record: 222222 [
{variable number of lines and content}
]
Record: 333333 [
text
text
text
Start to do another thing
text
]
```

---

The job:

```
awk '/^Record: .*\[$/{ f=1; n=$2 }/^\]/{f=0}f && /^Start/{ print n, $0 }' input.txt
```

The output:

```
111111 Start to do this thing
333333 Start to do another thing
```